# My husband left the water running from the hose and the well is dry!

Tags: well-pump

My husband was refilling the hot tub and left the hose on. I have arrived at our cabin to find the well is obviously dry. After reading some of the comments on the site I have unplugged the non submerged pump but have no idea what else to do. I have no experience with wells. This is a new property with a new well shared by one other household. What next?

Comment: What made your hsband forget about filling the tub? You will need to change practices as doing this often will not be good, especially relations with the neighbors...

Answer (score 1):

Give it time. Most wells have a pretty consistent "production rate" based on underground geography (maybe there is a better word).  I've grown up around wells all my life and every one is different.

Give the well time to recharge (let water refill the well drill pipe. )

Because the well ran dry and the above ground pump started "sucking air" it may need to be re-primed. Not a hard procedure to do.

We can help you with specific instructions if you let us know more details of your well system, pump, well logs (drilling logs) drawdown tests.  But esp. the details of your pump so we can help you safely restart it.   Some wells with limited capacity have controls in place to prevent damage to a pump in the case of excessive draw.  That would be another important thing for us to know.

Comment: Yes the pump May have overheated and shut down it will refill, make sure if there is a safety system to reset it, sometimes this is as simple as cycling the circuit breaker off and on , the water may be a bit muddy when the pump starts again that’s normal, it happens but will not hurt anything if the pump survived.+